# Error: Cannot import name 'AtrousConvolution2D' from 'keras.layers'

Tags: python, keras, computer-vision

I am trying to carry out saliency estimation for which I am trying to use AtrousConvolution2D in my program. However, I am being shown the error that

importError: cannot import name 'AtrousConvolution2D' from 'keras.layers'

I have tried to refer to this particular [documentation](https://conx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/keras/layers/convolutional.html) to see how it is to be imported. But I am not able to understand what "from ..legacy.layers" means in the following code snippet:

```
from ..legacy.layers import AtrousConvolution2D

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5swHU.png)

The following is my code snippet:
```

Comment: That is not the official Keras documentation...

Answer (score 0):

Keras documentation is https://keras.io/

Try it: `from keras.layers.legacy import AtrousConvolution2D`

Comment: use the latest version of keras (2.11.0)

Answer (score 0):

keras **AtrousConvolution2D** has been deprecated, Use **Conv2D** instead.

Where parameters are updated to:

```
atrous_rate => dilation_rate
border_mode => padding
```

Here is a function wrapper tooked from an older [keras fork](https://github.com/MarcBS/keras)

```
def AtrousConvolution2D(*args, **kwargs):
    from ..layers import Conv2D
    if 'atrous_rate' in kwargs:
        rate = kwargs.pop('atrous_rate')
    else:
        rate = 1
    kwargs['dilation_rate'] = rate
    warnings.warn('The `AtrousConvolution2D` layer '
                  ' has been deprecated. Use instead '
                  'the `Conv2D` layer with the `dilation_rate` '
                  'argument.')
    return Conv2D(*args, **kwargs)
```